# Download video from Microsoft Stream

Tags: video, download, video-streaming, microsoft-teams

I'd like to download video from Microsoft Teams, or better yet, from Microsoft Stream. I read that [this function is available only for the owner](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/play-and-share-a-meeting-recording-in-teams-7d7e5dc5-9ae4-4b94-8589-27496037e8fa).

The problem is the following: from tomorrow my university is starting streaming lectures because in Italy there is a big number of people with COVID-19 and the universities are closed. For this reason, and because my internet connection is not so good, I need to download the video lectures uploaded from the professors.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Have a look at this project on github. Its called [destreamer](https://github.com/snobu/destreamer) and basically does what you want. Depends on your University, you can find a version customized with the specific automated login for your school and for sure one is for the Milano Politecnico which is an italian university that goes under the name PoliDown.

Destreamer works by grapping the m3u streaming and combine it back using FFMPEG.

Comment: It requires some familiarity with the Linux command line but it works.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: better now ? i did some edits hope its better

Comment: It (now) works in environments that use proxies and/or SSO to protect the videos. I had to fix the code to work in my environment; I submitted a patch for it. https://github.com/snobu/destreamer/pull/123

Comment: I just tried it. 
It was extremely easy to install (I had to `npm install typescript --save` prior to `npm run build` since I was getting `... Error: Cannot find module '.../destreamer/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc' ...`, other than that it worked nicely).
And it was easy to use, simply `./destreamer.sh -i "<URL>"`.

Comment: Someone packaged destreamer as an executable, do check out the video and download the zip file (64bit and 32 bit availalbe). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uLQLCpji7pc

Disclaimer: I am not the content creater and I am not sure if this breaches the terms of service.

Comment: It works great !

Answer (score 2):

Download the microsoft stream app in android/apple phones or tablets and there you can save it for offline. Unfortunately there is no app in Windows.

Comment: Hi @Starkster, i tried it, but i don't find the file; i checked in file folder, video and photo folder, onedrive, but there isn't. Can you share a screenshot please?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi you won't find it as it is encrypted. Refer to this link, section "How offline video playback works": https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-stream-blog/watch-content-offline-using-stream-mobile-apps/ba-p/357939

Comment: I don't see the option for storing the video offline. Is it still there for you all? The instructions say to "select the action sheet for the video". On iPhone I click on the three dots and it brings up a sheet at the bottom of the display, but it has the options "Share", and "Remove from favorits". It doesn't have "Make available offline". I'm sad.

Answer (score 1):

On teams PC copy the link of the video and send it to yourself to open it on your smartphone with stream android. There you will be able to download it on your smartphone.

Answer (score 0):

In Teams and Streams, unless the recorder shares it with you, you will not be able to directly record it, unless the creator (your professor) set the permissions to enable that, as per the link above. I would suggest you contact the professor to make sure they have their IT department show them how to do that, [as Indiana University has done](https://kb.iu.edu/d/azae), now that Microsoft has [enabled cross-site recordings](https://office365itpros.com/2020/01/21/teams-meeting-recordings-stream/).

Once your professor does enable it, [selecting the lecture in Streams](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/stream/portal-download-video) allows recording.

An imperfect solution until the professor does enable downloads would be to use [Audacity](https://audacityteam.org) (which allows you to select the audio stream and record it with no patch cord) or another audio recording app with a patch cord from your sound output jack to your sound input jack, and record audio only.

If your PC has a webcam, its app *may* allow you to record int incoming stream (but no promises).

Comment: If you have an nVidia GPU, ShadowPlay could capture it but it needs to be recorded live.

Comment: No need to use patch cords with Audacity; https://www.howtogeek.com/217348/how-to-record-the-sound-coming-from-your-pc-even-without-stereo-mix/  And if you have a webcam, the included software may give you the ability to do video screen captures.